# How to create terraform map variable from script inside main.tf?

Tags: terraform, devops, hcl

I have a `main.tf` that looks like this:

```
module "my-module" {
  source = "./modules/my-module"
  mymap = "${var.mymap}"
}
```

and the following `variables.tf` file as shown:

```
variable "mymap" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
  }
}
```

I would like to run a script that sets the `mymap` map whenever `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` is executed. I know that terraform supports *external data source* as described in the official documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html) and that I could do something like this:

```
data "external" "example" {
  program = ["sh", /example-data-source.sh"]
} 

module "my-module" {
  source = "./modules/my-module"
  mymap = "${data.external.example.result}" # this is the output from example-data-source.sh
}
```

The problem is that the output is a JSON nested object and the `mymap` should be in an HCL format as far as I understand. With the current setup i'm getting this error:

```
command "sh" produced invalid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into go value of type string
```

The JSON is valid (i've checked).

So I'm wondering what is the correct way doing this? What am I missing?

P.S - I'm aware of setting an env variable `TF_VAR_mymap` *before* running *terraform* commands . However, that means I would need to do something like `TF_VAR_mymap=$(./somescript) terraform plan` and I would like to avoid it.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your problem that you want to pass different values of same variables to different environments? Say `setting1 = true` in production and `setting2 = false` in development?

Comment: Also terraform accepts json as valid variable files. e..g: variables.json `{ "setting1": true }` can be read and assigned to variables defined in variables.tf when using the plan command `terraform plan -var-file=/.variables.json`

Comment: I'm aware of this option - I would like to calculate a variable map based on a script output - the map will basically contain sensitive data - usernames, passwords etc. I've edited the post and removed the dev,prod keys to avoid confusion

Comment: @AntonioGomezAlvarado did you see an error message when you tried the final example you shared? If so, could you include that error in your question?

Comment: I've edited my post and added the error output @MartinAtkins, thank you!